# Split mysql_fetch_array result into two different two different rows in front end

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an set of array from my sql query

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [DSR] => 1016130
            [aplan] => $90-Standard
            [plan] => $44-Standard
            [cli] => 089561287
            [mobile] => 0428333999
        )
```

Now this is displaying in a single row but I am trying to split it in two rows by key [aplan] and [plan].

Current output

```
1|1016130|$90-Standard|$44-Standard|089561287|0428333999
```

Desire out will be

```
1|1016130|$90-Standard|089561287|0428333999
2|1016130|$44-Standard|089561287|0428333999
```

Will appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you try anything??

Comment: Yes I tried using foreach but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your 0 index is `$arr`. Notice that you have the same id, so the first value of output should be 1. If you want as 1, 2.. Then need some furnish..

```
$plan = array();
$aplan = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'aplan' || $key == 'plan'){
        if($key == 'aplan')
            $aplan[] = $value;
        else
            $plan[] = $value;
    }
    else{
        $plan[] = $value;
        $aplan[] = $value;
    }
}
echo implode("|", $aplan); // 1|1016130|$90-Standard|089561287|0428333999
echo implode("|", $plan);  // 1|1016130|$44-Standard|089561287|0428333999
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is not what I want. I am using kendo grid so I want to display the values in desired pattern there. Right Now it is being displayed as single row.

Comment: You can make it from the array `$aplan` and `$plan`.